# Windows software to record a USB web camera in full HD (similar to “Flix”)

Tags: windows, photography, webcam

I am going on a smaller roadtrip and am wanting to make a time-lapse. I purchased a windshield mount, long usb cable, and an HD webcam to do the capturing. I have an existing laptop to do the recording. Someone on this forum recommended using [Flix](http://www.nimisis.com/projects/flix) (by nimisis.com), but I cannot seem to get it to work in HD. It only wants to work in the standard low quality defaults. To change settings, you have to edit the program registry settings. I have followed the website directions closely but cannot get it to work.

Are there any other software programs for Windows that I am able to use? Any other ideas out there?

**Requirements:**

- Runs on Windows
- Captures stills from an USB connected webcam
- Adjustable settings (at least for interval)
- Supports high quality (full HD)
- Easy to install and configure (no fiddling with registry entries)
- Either free or less than $20

Comment: Have you tried [VLC](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3311/583)? I am not sure whether it supports HD capturing with your webcam.

Answer (score 2):

[Yawcam](http://www.yawcam.com/index.php) can do what you want I think.

It:

- Runs on Windows.
- Captures stills from a USB webcam.
- Has lots of settings (see screenshot below).
- Easy to install and configure.
- Freeware.

The only one I'm not sure about would be the full HD requirement. I'll go test it out and see what I can find out.

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I've used yawcam quite a bit, and I find it one of the best webcam softwares I've ever found.

Comment: I never was able to find out how it handled the full HD requirment, sorry.

Comment: I like Yawcam but note that it requires Java and by default it uses uPNP to configure your router - publishing your webcam out on the internet!