# capture the screen and capture via laptop video

Tags: linux, open-source, video, ubuntu, screen-recording

I want to prepare a presentation. What I need is a software which, capture :

1. the screen
2. my voice via my laptop microphone
3. my face via my laptop camera

What I am looking for two screen. One is the main screen which capture the desktop, which is my PowerPoint. and the another screen is my face . which its place is on top the of main screen and smaller than it.

I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Where should the video streams appear? VLC media player is capable of recording the webcam, the screen and the microphone. But it cannot record two video inputs at the same time (that would be illogical). However, you could open two VLC instances.

Comment: @ComFreek OMG, I did not know that VLC media player is capable of recording the webcam, the screen and the microphonem.

Comment: From ComFreek suggestion : http://www.wikihow.com/Screen-Capture-to-File-Using-VLC

Comment: Did my suggestion answer your question? If so, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @ComFreek yes, thanks for your help. now I have another problem: I am looking for video editor which have this ability to merge two video on ubuntu.

Comment: my result should me a video of my powerpoint while my face is on the screen too at the same time.

Comment: That is another question. Therefore, please post a new request for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

- Can capture the screen
- Can capture a webcam
- Can record audio (in conjunction with one video input if desired)

I have already posted a manual on how to do the things mentioned above in another answer: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3311/583